# Opening a buffer as a file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm testing a solution locally using

```
    const edi_buffer_handle = await fs.open(path);
    for await (const line of edi_buffer_handle.readLines()) {
        // instructions
    }
```

Now, I'm trying to adapt this code to accept data coming from files attached to web requests, using 'express-fileupload'. I do NOT want to write files onto the disk to open then delete them. I want to save I/O, and read the content line by line like a file. Using this library, the file data is accessed via an object of type Buffer.

My desired solution would be something similar to:

```
  const file_buffer = await fs.open(req.files.file.data); //Buffer
  for await (const line of file_buffer.readLines()) {
    //same thing
  }
```

Is there any solution?